# Is it possible to view this with a web browser, and how?

Tags: html

```
       http://polaris/Frameset_BSC.html
```

I was asked to edit this, but when I copied and paste this to the browser I get an error message. How do I view the above link?

Thanks for the help. I'm new to web development.

Comment: You need to provide more details. Why were you asked to edit an HTML file if you don't know how to do it is my question though.

Comment: `polaris` is not a normal domain name.  What about `polaris.com`?  You should be asking the person who gave you link for more information rather than asking us to guess.

Comment: My guess is that `polaris` is the name of a server accessible from the company's subnet.

Answer (score 3):

Your URL has three parts:

```
protocol:    http
host name:   polaris
path:        Frameset_BSC.html
```

The protocol makes sense as one would most likely use a browser to communicate via the Hyper Text Transfer Protocol (HTTP).

The host name 'POLARIS' without a domain extension (.com, .net, etc.) suggests the host is local to your local area network.

So either the host name is wrong or you don't have access to the host (POLARIS) on your network (for either security reasons or configuration -- see Paul D's comment about `hosts` file).

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the sort of domain that a company might set up on its internal network to run a site from.

You might need to edit your hosts file (`/etc/hosts` on Mac OS X, `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows) to point that domain to the right IP address, by adding a line like this:

```
101.10.101.101  polaris
```

(The numbers would be replaced by the actual IP address of whatever server `polaris` is meant to refer to.)